# Is it possible to set a dynamic -minrelaytxfee?

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, mempool

When I start bitcoind, I like to set a `-minrelaytxfee` to save bandwidth on transactions that will likely never make it in to the blockchain (because their fees are too low).

However, when the network is under low load, I would be happy to reduce the `-minrelaytxfee` so that my node receives more of the transactions on the network.

**Is there any way I can dynamically change the minrelaytxfee whilst my node is running?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.

However you could make your mempool smaller and that would have a similar effect. The mempool has its own `minmempoolfee`. The in-practice `minrelayfee` is the maximum of the `-minrelaytxfee` and the `minmempoolfee`. The `minmempoolfee` will change when the mempool becomes full, and decreases when it has space. So if you set your `-maxmempool` to be much smaller, you would get a similar effect to changing `-minrelaytxfee` dynamically.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, this is interesting to learn. Do you know of any documentation on how -maxmempool adjusts the minmempoolfee?

Comment: @inersha When transactions are evicted from the mempool due to being at the bottom of a too-large mempool when sorted by feerate, the effective minrelayfee is raised to be the feerate of the evicted transactions.

Comment: @PieterWuille Excellent, thanks Pieter. What causes minmempoolfee to return back to a lower value (i.e. back to -minrelaytxfee)? Is it when a transaction is received that does not have to evict another one?

Comment: It continuously goes down, very slowly, halving every 3 to 12 hours, until it has to be bumped again due to an eviction.